# NEdit_How to use the Shell on NEdit to save the file - LINUX base

Tags: linux, save, backup, nedit

I am working on the script on NEdit with LINUX environment.
But I can't reach one of the funciton of the script.
*I would like to add "save" file function at the script, but it seems not possible.
I checked the NEdit Help document, it mentions the "Make Backup Copy" function is UNIX only.
Not sure anyone has experience on it? -> To automatically save/backup the file after you call the script with LINUX environment.

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Make Backup Copy
On Save, write a backup copy of the file as it existed before the Save command with the extension .bck (Unix only).
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/labman/nedit/n6.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the macros or the functions?

`save()` just saves the current file (same as Ctrl-S)

`save_as_dialog()` will bring up a dialogue to save the file

You can put them in buttons from the macro menus or you can define a functions and then add that function to a macro button.